# Window throwing memory exception for unknown reason, gtkmm and c++

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I'm writing a small program that uses gtkmm to create a gui display. Last time I worked on it, it was working fine. Today I ran the program and it crashed because of an unhandled bad_alloc. I can catch the exception but my window still won't open. It's also freezing for a while before it crashes. I'm at a loss and my searches haven't turned anything up so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit- after I could not recreate the problem in a smaller program, I stashed my changes and rewrote what I hadn't committed. The problem never came back so I may never know what caused it.

Comment: Try to make a small program that reproduces the problem. It's called a [mcve] here. Show the code for that program when you've written it.

Comment: A generic answer: try to debug this program using GDB https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

Comment: I already ran it in gdb but I forgot to mention in my post that the exception is originating in app->run. I'll see if I can create a minimal reproducible example and get back to you.

Comment: @ECJones For other people to have a reasonable chance to help out, post a short piece of code that produces the same problem you have.